# Web service not returning integer data in an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VS2003 Web Reference for a WCF Service has Extra "IdSpecified" Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184245/vs2003-web-reference-for-a-wcf-service-has-extra-idspecified-parameter)

Thanks everyone.  I totally missed that.  Yes, the class name is awful.

I have a web service (ASMX) that returns an object which contains an array.

I first define my response object:

```
APIResponse response = new APIResponse();
```

Fill a datatable:

```
dtHolder = SqlHelper.ExecuteDatatable(connstring, CommandType.StoredProcedure, strSelect, aParams);
```

Create a holder for the results of my query:

```
    API036RsBkgDetRec[] BkgDetRec_Array = new API036RsBkgDetRec[dtHolder.Rows.Count];
            int i = 0;

            foreach (DataRow row in dtHolder.Rows)
            {
                BkgDetRec_Array[i] = new API036RsBkgDetRec();

                BkgDetRec_Array[i].eqoEqszId = row[0].ToString();
                BkgDetRec_Array[i].eqoEqtpId = row[1].ToString();
                BkgDetRec_Array[i].eqoEqhtId = row[2].ToString();
                BkgDetRec_Array[i].qty = Convert.ToInt32(row[3]);
                BkgDetRec_Array[i].receiveQty = Convert.ToInt32(row[4]);
                BkgDetRec_Array[i].emptyTally = Convert.ToInt32(row[5]);
                BkgDetRec_Array[i].maxEmpty = Convert.ToInt32(row[6]);
                BkgDetRec_Array[i].chsQty = Convert.ToInt32(row[7]);
                BkgDetRec_Array[i].chsTally = Convert.ToInt32(row[8]);

                i++;
            }
```

and populate the array I am returning (bkgDetTable) with the holder array I just populated above:

```
response.bkgDetTable = BkgDetRec_Array;
```

When I capture the output, I see that none of the integer fields are being created even though when I step through the code, they are being populated with real numbers.  The object API036RsBkgDetRec also has them defined as integer values.  Only the ones defined as string are coming across.

```
<bkgDetTable xmlns="http://sdfsd/xsd">
<eqoEqhtId>96</eqoEqhtId>
<eqoEqszId>40</eqoEqszId>
<eqoEqtpId>DR</eqoEqtpId>
</bkgDetTable>
```

Here is the definition of API036RsBkgDetRec:

```
public partial class API036RsBkgDetRec
{    
private int chsQtyField;

private bool chsQtyFieldSpecified;

private int chsTallyField;

private bool chsTallyFieldSpecified;

private int emptyTallyField;

private bool emptyTallyFieldSpecified;

private string eqoEqhtIdField;

private string eqoEqszIdField;

private string eqoEqtpIdField;

private int maxEmptyField;

private bool maxEmptyFieldSpecified;

private int qtyField;

private bool qtyFieldSpecified;

private int receiveQtyField;

private bool receiveQtyFieldSpecified;

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
public int chsQty
{
    get
    {
        return this.chsQtyField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.chsQtyField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
public bool chsQtySpecified
{
    get
    {
        return this.chsQtyFieldSpecified;
    }
    set
    {
        this.chsQtyFieldSpecified = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
public int chsTally
{
    get
    {
        return this.chsTallyField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.chsTallyField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
public bool chsTallySpecified
{
    get
    {
        return this.chsTallyFieldSpecified;
    }
    set
    {
        this.chsTallyFieldSpecified = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=2)]
public int emptyTally
{
    get
    {
        return this.emptyTallyField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.emptyTallyField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
public bool emptyTallySpecified
{
    get
    {
        return this.emptyTallyFieldSpecified;
    }
    set
    {
        this.emptyTallyFieldSpecified = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Order=3)]
public string eqoEqhtId
{
    get
    {
        return this.eqoEqhtIdField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.eqoEqhtIdField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Order=4)]
public string eqoEqszId
{
    get
    {
        return this.eqoEqszIdField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.eqoEqszIdField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Order=5)]
public string eqoEqtpId
{
    get
    {
        return this.eqoEqtpIdField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.eqoEqtpIdField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=6)]
public int maxEmpty
{
    get
    {
        return this.maxEmptyField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.maxEmptyField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
public bool maxEmptySpecified
{
    get
    {
        return this.maxEmptyFieldSpecified;
    }
    set
    {
        this.maxEmptyFieldSpecified = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=7)]
public int qty
{
    get
    {
        return this.qtyField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.qtyField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
public bool qtySpecified
{
    get
    {
        return this.qtyFieldSpecified;
    }
    set
    {
        this.qtyFieldSpecified = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=8)]
public int receiveQty
{
    get
    {
        return this.receiveQtyField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.receiveQtyField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
public bool receiveQtySpecified
{
    get
    {
        return this.receiveQtyFieldSpecified;
    }
    set
    {
        this.receiveQtyFieldSpecified = value;
    }
}
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can we see the definition of API036RsBkgDetRec?

Comment: Is this a WCF service or ASMX?

Comment: The developer that choose `API036RsBkgDetRec` as a class name should face a trial and be sentenced by a jury of peers.

Comment: Joe, don't change the title to (solved) if your problem is solved, that does not mark it as Solved in the UI. If one of the responses solved your problem, click the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This does look like a duplicate of a similar problem, so if mods want to delete, that's fine by me.

Answer (score 4):

For all the `INT` fields,  you have two fields:

- the actual `int` field which I'm sure you're already setting to the proper value (`private int emptyTallyField;`)
- but you **also** have a field called `private bool emptyTallyFieldSpecified;` which **must be set to `true`** - otherwise that int value you set **will not be serialized out**

The reason for this is because for a reference-type field like a `string` field, you can have `NULL` to represent the "there is no value" aspect, and you can have an empty string or any other string in there.

For value types, like `int` - how else would you represent the "there is no value specified" case? If you set the int field to 0 - is that 0 because you want that "zero" as the value, or is that "0" because you really want to say "there is no value". For this reason, all value types have this additional `(fieldname)specified` property which indicates whether or not an actual value is present. If that specified-flag is not set (and it's not set by default), then you have no value - thus nothing gets serialized out.

Answer (score 1):

You will notice that for each property value type (integer, double, DateTime, ...) you have a `XXXSpecified` boolean property. For example you have:

```
public int maxEmpty
```

and

```
public bool maxEmptySpecified
```

Those properties are generated when you import a WCF web service using wsdl.exe (or Add Web Reference in Visual Studio). You need to set them to `true` every-time you set their corresponding value type property value.

I agree that this is total crap but, that's how it is. ASMX is deprecated now.